# Загрузить БД на удаленный сервер

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть программа на c# : сама программа + база данных созданная в MS SQL Server Manager Studio. На данный момент БД находится на моем ПК (Windows) но в дальнейшем её необходимо загрузить на сервер с Linucs (управление базой через phpMyAdmin). Вопрос какие могут возникнуть сложности с выгрузкой БД ? Не будет ли проблем если на сервере mySQL а у меня MS SQL Server ? В программе на C# используется SqlClient(SqlCommand, SqlConnection ect) и на локальном сервере с Windows все работает хорошо, но не возникнет ли проблем когда база будет перенесена на удаленный Linucs?

Comment: `какие могут возникнуть сложности с выгрузкой БД ? Не будет ли проблем если на сервере mySQL а у меня MS SQL Server ?` Сложности возникнут, и большие. Далеко не все конструкции MS SQL реализованы в MySQL, некоторые внешне такие же на самом деле работают иначе, а местами даже аналог подобрать сложно.

Comment: конструкции это запросы? mySQL и MS SQL Server Manager Studio это же разные СУБД а не разные языки запросов?

Comment: Диалекты то языков разные.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под диалектами? Пример у меня есть запрос : "select * from table" а таблица создана в SQL Manager Studio в чем будет сложность серверу с ней работать?

Comment: @Сергей Простейшие конструкции работать будут везде. Но как только дело дойдёт до чего-то более-менее сложного, начнётся развлекуха. Например, в MySQL вместо `SELECT TOP x ...` придётся использовать `SELECT ... LIMIT x`, а для реализации `SELECT TOP x PERCENT ...` потребуется уже сильно поизвращаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас будет море проблем. Используйте .Net провайдер MySQL, установите MySQL на рабочую машину, с помощью в MySQLWorkbench попробуйте в ручном режиме через генерацию скриптов перенести БД с MS SQL на MySQL.
Дальнейшее сопровождение и доработку можно производить MySQLWorkbench, это лучше и удобнее чем phpMyAdmin.
Перепишите код с использованием классов MySql.Data.MySqlClient, почти все аналогично System.Data.SQLClient

Comment: Рабочая машина это в данном случае мой ПК или сервер? Куда Workbench поставить?

Comment: Ваша Windows машина на которой вы кодируете.

Comment: А для дальнейшей доработки вместо phpMyadmin можно Workbench поставить ?

Comment: Конечно, в отличие от phpMyAdmin уже не нужен php+апач или nginxp, у вас будет чисто линукс машина под сервер БД.